# Javascript: Array Length not calculating

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm going to chalk this up to just being tired, but I have a simple `if` statement that checks the size of an array.  As you can see from the image, the length of the array is 4 and my if statement is:

```
if blankFields.length > 0 {
```

Even though it should run the function, it always skips the function.

As you can see from the image, when I hover over `blankFields`, you see the contents and length of the array.  However, if I hover just over the `.length` I am told it is "undefined".

What am I missing?
[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: **lentgh** ? Thats probably why..

Comment: tyops: Teh bnae fo porgammrers

Comment: Do you know how long I have been starring at this.  Geezz - Thanks guys.  BIG THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yup, you're tired. `lentgh` -> **`length`**

Comment: Might I acquire, perchance, ye olde lengthe?

Comment: Very funny :) - Do you know how long I have been starring at this.  BIG THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!